# How to browse zip files in vifm

Tags: vifm

I want to be able to browse zip files and their subfolders from vifm.
By default(after a clean installation) the vifm does not support such functionality.

Answer (score 8):

If you didn't alter sample `vifmrc`, then it already contains necessary configuration to open zip files using [FUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace). It looks like this:

```
filetype *.zip,*.jar,*.war,*.ear,*.oxt
       \ {Mount with fuse-zip}
       \ FUSE_MOUNT|fuse-zip %SOURCE_FILE %DESTINATION_DIR,
```

As you can see it invokes [`fuse-zip`](https://bitbucket.org/agalanin/fuse-zip) to mount archive as a directory. FUSE is probably present and working (assuming that you use GNU/Linux, but there is also OS X analogue; Windows seems to had one too, but it's probably incompatible with FUSE mounters out there), so all you need is to install `fuse-zip`.

The same way you can browse anything if there is a FUSE module for it (tar, rar, iso, 7z).